# mmenu hide address bar when expanded on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I am using mmenu (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) jQuery plugin for a mobile page and I am trying to keep the address bar on the iPhone hidden at all times. I currently have:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
      // Set a timeout...
      setTimeout(function(){
      // Hide the address bar!
      window.scrollTo(0, 1);
   }, 0);
});
```

but this only hide on page load so when I click the left menu and right menu buttons and the menus expand out the address bar reappears. Was wondering if there was a way to keep the address bar hidden when the menus are in their expanded state.

Comment: Can you not just add the `scrollTo(0,1)` action in the events for your menu interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue should be fixed in the latest version of the plugin:
http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/download.php#changelog_3_2

Comment: Would you mind explaining on how to use this function? I tried calling it but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: You don't need to call any function.
The plugin should automatically detect when to use the fix and apply it.
Basically, the plugin adds an extra 60px padding-bottom to the body to trick the browser into thinking the page is larger than the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to fix my issue.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, height=device-height, width=device-width, user-scalable = no">
```