# using mmenu iPhoneAddressBar function

Tags: jquery, mmenu

Trying to utilize the iPhoneAddressBar function but doesnt seem to be working. Was wondering if anyone has an example of how to use this?

jQuery Plugin - http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/

Edit going to link to my previous question as it relates.

[mmenu hide address bar when expanded on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279064/mmenu-hide-address-bar-when-expanded-on-mobile?noredirect=1#comment26813646_18279064)

Comment: What do you mean by not working,ru getting any error message in console ?

Answer (score 0):

This variable:

```
$.fn.mmenu.support.iPhoneAddressBar
```

Is set to true if you are on an iPhone or iPod, are not using Chrome, are not in the standalone-mode (via the "web-app-capable" metatag) and the metatag "viewport" does not contain "height=device-height".

It is set to false otherwise.

Comment: So on my iphone its returning true, but still not seeing it. I'm not using the standalone-mode meta tag. And here is my current viewport tag. <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, user-scalable = no">

Comment: What are you "not seeing"?
Try: alert( $.fn.mmenu.support.iPhoneAddressBar )

Comment: I am not seeing the menu bar hide at all in safari on iphone. The alert returns true.

Comment: The address bar should not hide if it wasn't already hidden. It should only stay hidden if it already was hidden.